# Is there any way to attach a callback function to a route in an Angular routing module?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am building a large app on Angular that uses feature modules with child routes. Each child section is rendered through a section specific layout, which for the MVP sets the state for child pages. For example:

`/app/projects/yJEBuuOmmRv7WuVomGkb` will load the project `yJEBuuOmmRv7WuVomGkb` into the state container on any child routes.

I've experimented with watching the router events, but have run into some challenging situations where the app is dealing with different routers in different contexts (child vs parent).

I would like to do this in the route definition and was wondering if there is any way to attach a callback function to a route that can capture the route params and apply them to the state container.

For example, something like this pseudocode:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PageLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: PagesComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'admin/settings',
        component: PageSettingsComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'admin/publishing',
        component: PagePublishingComponent
      },
      {
        path: ':pageId',
        component: PageDetailLayoutComponent,
        
        // pseudo code!!!
        onRoute: (params => {
          StateContainer.set('page', params.pageId);
        }),
        
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: PageComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class PagesRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some options to add data to routes.

1. data property in your route:

example:

```
{
   path: 'heroes',
   component: HeroListComponent,
   data: { title: 'Heroes List' 
 }
```

From angular docs:

> The data property in the third route is a place to store arbitrary
>   data associated with this specific route. The data property is
>   accessible within each activated route. Use it to store items such as
>   page titles, breadcrumb text, and other read-only, static data. You'll
>   use the resolve guard to retrieve dynamic data later in the guide.

2. Resolvers

example:

```
{
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    resolve: { hero: HeroResolver }
}
```

From angular docs:

> In summary, you want to delay rendering the routed component until all
>   necessary data have been fetched.

For more info: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-guard
So it means if you call an api endpoint that give data to your component, you should use resolver.

Maybe you could invoke the `StateContainer.set` in component's ngOnInit method.